# present or past in this context of opening a claim

Tags: past-tense

I **wanted to inform** you that if I haven't received any updates from Australia Post regarding my shipment by February 21st , I will need to escalate the matter by opening a PayPal claim."I believe it's fair to give you this advance notice before taking any further steps. Thank you for your attention to this matter."

if I wrote

**I want to inform** you that if I have not  received any updates from Australia Post regarding my shipment by February 21st, I will need to escalate the matter by opening a PayPal claim."I believe it's fair to give you this advance notice before taking any further steps. Thank you for your attention to this matter."
What is the most suitable tense here  present or past simple  present is not too harsh or too direct

Comment: People _do_ use the past tense in this context - "I wanted to ask you...", maybe with the sense "I've wanted to ask for some time and now I'm doing so". The present tense is fine, though. You can also say "I wish to inform you...".

Comment: present with present perfect    have not received  by after is fine ?

Comment: Please punctuate properly. If you mean "Is _I want to inform you that I have not received..._ fine?" - yes, it is.

Comment: "I want to inform you that" is padding that works in speech but dilutes your seriousness in writing. I'd start with "If I have not received."

Answer (score 0):

I suggest we use the present tense because you intention is still there.

Why would we want to be indirect?  Being direct doesn’t mean we must be harsh; we won't want to use phrases like **I hereby**.

My suggestions are

> I **write** to inform you that if I **do not receive**...

> **Please be informed** that if I **do not receive**...

Comment: why is it not possible to write I want to inform you that if I  have not received ......

Comment: I think it's possible too to use *want*.  I personally prefer *do not receive*.

Comment: why  do you prefer do not receive by instead have not received by , present perfect is generally used with by (like  a deadline)

Comment: There's a similar post [do-not-receive-something-vs-have-not-received-something-by-a-given-time](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/48771/do-not-receive-something-vs-have-not-received-something-by-a-given-time).   I agree that the difference is very little.